# Make Pyinstaller pack up files into an exe

Tags: python, operating-system, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make a **single executable file** with a data file contained within it.

I tried `--add-data "filename.png;."` and it seemed to be working, but then how do I access that file if it's sewed into exe? Can't use default `with open()` because it reference a file in relative directory.
It's essential that it's a single file application rather than exe with resources